# ASP.Net Not to Print Button

Tags: asp.net, events, printing

I've an application form in my ASP.Net page. And I want to Print this page when user clicks on the Button. But unfortunately, that trigger button printed on the paper. How can I get rid of that button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10174153/138938

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use print css and use this style sheet to hide button when printing form.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="URL to your print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

In your aspx:

```
<asp:Button id="btn" runat="server" CssClass="button-c"/>
```

in print.css file add

```
.button-c {display:none !important;}
```